# validating c++ user input in specific format

Tags: c++

How to validate user input in some specific format. For example,

Social Security Number, in the format **xxx-xx-xxxx**, where x is a digit within the range 0 through 9. Only accept valid Social Security Numbers (with no alphabetic characters)

Employee number, in the format **xxx-L**, where x is a digit within the range 0 through 9, and the L is a letter within the range A through M.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <string>

class Employee
{
protected:
    string name;
    string ssn; // social security number in format xxx-xx-xxxx
    string empNo; // employee number in format xxx-L
    string date;

public:Employee(){
    
}

void printEmp()
{
    cout << "\n Name : " << name;
    cout << "\n Hire Date : " << date;
    cout << "\n Soc Sec # : " << ssn;
    cout << "\n Employee # : " << empNo;
} 

void getName(){
}

void setName(string n){
name = n
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you are not taking `-` in input.
You can simply loop the string and use functions like `isalpha` and `isdigit`.
For specific ranges as A to M
You can compare it directly.
For example:

```
string s="ABCXYZ";
bool satisfied = false;
for(int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i){
    if(s[i]<="M" && s[i]>="A"){
        //this satisfies your criteria
        satisfied = true;
    }else {
        satisfied = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(!satisfied){
    cout<<"Invalid input"<<"\n";
}
```

For `isalpha` and `isdigit` functions you can just google them up!